# PDF of the distance between two points on a rectangle

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a rectangle with side lengths $1$ and $a$. On both sides with length $1$ we choose two points uniformly and independently (one from each side). If $X$ is the random variable of the distance between these two points, what is the probability density function of $X$?

I don't even know how to approach this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Start by introducing variables: Let the two points be $(0,X_1)$ and $(a,X_2)$, where the $X_i$ are uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, say. Express your distance as a formula involving the $X_i$.

Comment: $\sqrt(a^2+(X_1+X_2)^2)$ is the distance, now what should I do?

Comment: Nope, it's not.

Comment: $\sqrt{a^2+(X_2-X_1)^2}$ is the distance. The possible values are in $[a,\sqrt{a^2+1}]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z=X^2=a^2+(X_2-X_1)^2=a^2+Y=a^2+T^2$.
$$P(a^2+u^2<Z<a^2+u^2+dz)= P(u^2<Y<u^2+dy)$$
$$f_z(z)dz = f_y(y)dy$$
Given the simple convolution of $X_1$ and $X_2$:
$$f_t(t)=(1-|t|)$$
for $-1<t<1$ and zero otherwise. Transform $T$ to $Y$:
$$f_y(y) = {2 f_t(\sqrt{y})\over 2\sqrt{y}}= {1\over \sqrt{y}}-1$$
Transform from $Y$ to $Z$:
$$f_z(z) = f_y(z-a^2)={1\over \sqrt{z-a^2}}-1$$
Finally transform from $Z$ to $X$:
$$f_x(x) = f_z(x^2)\, 2x={2x\over \sqrt{x^2-a^2}}-2x$$
for $a<x<\sqrt{a^2+1}$ and zero otherwise.